# looking for a recommended design pattern for retrieving specific attributes via REST

Tags: rest

consider `http://server/noun.json?noun_id=<integer>`. What if the noun has 100s of attributes, and I want to retrieve either all or some? I am thinking of something like

```
// a canned set of attributes
http://server/noun.json?noun_id=<integer>

// all attributes
http://server/noun.json?noun_id=<integer>?columns=all

// specified attributes
http://server/noun.json?noun_id=<integer>?columns=[col1,col3,col4,col7]

// to help make a decision, a "describe" returns a list of attributes
http://server/noun.json?describe=?
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with your 3rd option. Here's an example of a production API that retrieves a report, and requests that the report's results be filtered by a number of criteria via URL params.

https://demos.nubic.northwestern.edu/psc/api/v1/docs#d2e2591

**The API call takes many options:**

```
/reports/scheduled-activities?study&site&state&activity-type&label&start-date&end-date&start-ideal-date&end-ideal-date&responsible-user&person-id
```

Which allows running `reports` of `scheduled-activities` (a scheduled activity is just an item that appears on a calendar), and optionally filtering the results by the specified criteria. Specifying **no** filter criteria simply returns **all** `scheduled-activities` in the system.

For example, if I wanted a list of everything that "Joe Smith" had scheduled at the site `NU`, and assuming Joe had a person-id of `1234`, the API call might look something like:

`/reports/scheduled-activities?site=NU&person-id=1234`

Comment: There is a slight difference between your example and the original question - he's not filtering the resource returned, he's specifying which attributes to retrieve on each resource found.